# Search for brackets in a case insensitive using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

```
with open(logfile) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if re.search(string,line,re.IGNORECASE):
            print 'found line',line
```

So how to search string contains brackets,- characters using Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

s = "foo[bar]baz"
m = re.search("[\[\]]", s)
print m.group(0)
# => '['

t = "foo-bar]baz"
n = re.search("[\[\]]", t)
print n.group(0)
# => ']'
```

In fact, `re.IGNORECASE` is unnecessary since bracktes have no case.

**Edit:**

```
u = "foo\\-bar]baz"
o = re.search('[\[\]]', u) # Does this match the \ ?
print o.group(0)
# => ']'
# Behold!
```

Comment: It's not *unecessary* it's *wrong*. Inside a character class, it will match a literal \ in the input.

Comment: @veredesmarald, NO your are wrong here. A backslash is also in a character class the escape character and you need it if you want to add a `]` to your character class. If you want to add a literal backslash to your class you need to add an escaped backslash. There are not many characters that need to/should be escaped inside a character class, but there are, e.g. `]` or `-` (when not at the start or end). You need the backslash also as escape character to add predefined character classes like `\d` to your own class.

Comment: @stema OK, you are correct, but be aware this is a python (and probably other scripting languages?) specific thing. In a POSIX regex (`grep`, `sed`, etc) \ is always a literal in a character class, the correct way to include `]` is to include it as the first character; likewise `^` and `-` should be included as not the first, and first or last, respectively. They also don't support adding predefined classes so things like `[\dA-F]` wont work the way you want. I would still recommend using `[][]` to match square brackets, since it will work everywhere.

Comment: @veredesmarald, that are the small differences in the flavours ;). But I would not recommend to use `[][]`, because the behaviour differs also from language to language. [See Regexr](http://regexr.com?31q1l)